# Cyclic reference at maven build in a multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-shade-plugin

I want to package several modules into one executable JAR file.
For that I am using Maven Shade.
The 5 modules are called A,B,C,D,E for the example. 
The modules B,C,D,E have a dependency to the project A in each of their pom.

To build this JAR, I created a parent module containing these definitions:

```
<module>A</module>
<module>B</module>
<module>C</module>
<module>D</module>
<module>E</module>
```

Then, in the project A, on which depend the other projects, I define the Maven shade plugin. The thing is I have to specify there dependencies on the other projects so that it can package and take into account the other projects in the JAR. But these other projects have already defined a dependency in their pom to the project A.

So I have a cyclic reference of dependencies :

- one in the project A to B,C,D and E to package the JAR file
- ones in the projects B,C,D and E to A in order to use content in A

Do you know how I should specify in this architecture a way to do not have a cyclic reference like that and have the behaviour I would like ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a sixth module F that generates the executable jar. Then you don't have any cyclic dependencies.